# Lexik jwt bundle - login by username or email

Tags: symfony5, lexikjwtauthbundle

I use lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle 2.14 for login in a symfony 5.4 API project

I can login by username, or by email via config, but i can't have login by (username or email)

Even using X-debug, I couldn't find what to custom to do that

Does any of you have an idea ?